# Write unique keys from 'list of dictionaries' to csv as headers & also write relevant values under each header using Python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries;

```
information = [{'Edu':'School','Age':'40','Height':'5.11','DOB':'08091972','Name':'Jack'},
 {'Edu':'College','Age':'30','Height':'4.11','DOB':'05041982','Name':'Alex','Pro':'Teacher'},
 {'Name':'Elizabeth','Nickname':'Lizzy','DOB':'01012005'}]
```

I would like to write this to a csv.

[image]

So far I've been able to get the unique headers to be written to the csv like this...

```
unique_headers = []

for info in information:
    unique_headers.append(s.keys()) # append keys to a list - but this would take ages right? certainly not pythonic


ordered_fieldnames = set(flatten(unique_headers))

with open('profile.csv','wb') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=',', fieldnames=ordered_fieldnames)
    dw.writeheader() # unique headers are written
```

Now, how do I get the records written to the csv under the relevant headers?

Comment: The Python docs has the answer: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Comment: You can use `set.union` to get all the unique keys:
`reduce(set.union,(set(x.keys()) for x in information))`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary he already has printed the keys :P

Comment: @limelights but his method was certainly not pythonic as he mentioned it himself : *certainly not pythonic*.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that you are 100% correct in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
...
dw.writeheader()
dw.writerows(information)
```